# (wordpress) Show title & content of posts instead of the current page title & content?

Tags: wordpress, get, posts

I am trying to get my posts to load into the #portfolio div. I would like to display the title, content and a thumbnail. The code itself seems to work, but it shows me the title and content of my "Homepage". It is a one-page design. Is there a way to get the posts on this page? Below is the specific part of the code.

```
<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="head-title col-md-12">
      <h1 class="h1b">Portfolio</h1>
  </div>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <?php the_title(); ?>
       <?php the_content(); ?>
       <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Since it's probably useful to be able to look into the rest of the code of this page as well, I have posted it below. I hope you can help me out!

```
<?php /* Template Name: Homepage */ ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#navbar">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#oversuus">over suus</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="header">
  <div id="logo"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo.svg" /></div>
</div>

<div id="oversuus">
  <div class="head-title col-md-12">
      <h1 class="h1a">Over Suus</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="oversuus-text">
    <?php
    $page_id = 32; //id example
    $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
    echo $content;
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="oversuus-img">

  </div>
</div>

<div id="portfolio">
  <div class="head-title col-md-12">
      <h1 class="h1b">Portfolio</h1>
  </div>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <?php the_title(); ?>
       <?php the_content(); ?>
       <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div id="contact">
  <div class="head-title col-md-12">
      <h1 class="h1c">Contact</h1>
  </div>
  <?php
  $page_id = 34; //id example
  $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
  $title = $page_data->post_title;
  echo $content;
  ?>
</div>

<div id="questions">
  <p>
    x
  </p>
  <div class="mailbt">
    MAIL
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to look into the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class.

Comment: @cabrerahector Thank you! It's much easier to figure it out when you know where/how to look haha.

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know if I used the best way, I managed to fix my issue thanks to the suggestion of @cabrerahector. I'm still quite a noob at this as you can probably see, so I clearly hadn't thought it through enough. Just posting this in case there is another noob out there who can use this.

```
  <?php
          $query = new WP_Query( array(
         'post_type' => 'post',
         'orderby' => 'date',
         'order' => 'ASC',
         'posts_per_page' => 4
      ) );

      if( $query->have_posts() ) {
          while( $query->have_posts() ) {
              $query->the_post();
      ?>

          <?php the_title(); ?>
          <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
              $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full' );
               echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="200px" height="200px"  />';
          } ?>

          <?php

          }
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: Looks about right, except you should call `wp_reset_postdata();` after the `while` statement. Good job :)